# How to show a caret in standard HTML text using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning JavaScript and want to re-implement a typing game similar to `typeracer.com` where the aim is to type without errors as fast as you can.

On that page you type text into an input box and JavaScript evaluates your inputs against the target input. When I enter text into the input box the caret is not only shown in the input box itself but also in the target text like this:

[image]

See: `https://play.typeracer.com/`

Desired behavior: I want to create a `<span>` element in JavaScript and display a blinking caret after that even though it is not an input element.

How is that done? And how did you find out?

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is to check the text in the input and compare it with the text they need to type. As soon as this is done you need to mark the matched text with a different color. What i would do i to create a span that starts from the beginning of the sentence and follows the matching text. This span would have css rules that would modify the looks of the text inside it. The cursor you want to add could be a css element like a border on the spans right side or [an after pseudoelement][1]. thus all your js code needs to do is to compare the input with the sentence and move the  on the right position. The styling would be taken care of by the css.

You can also inspect the typerace.com website and see how they do it. This solution is how i would do it.
[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked the code and the element in front of the caret has it's own id. But when I inspect the corresponding css style it only includes a `text-decoration: underline`. So I don't think it is done using a css `::after`. You may also notice that the additional caret is blinking like the "original" one in the input box.

Comment: Yeah as i said this is how i would do it. Maybe they are styling the matching letters through javascript or something. Is your goal to create something that looks like their website or reproducing their code? The blinking cursor can be made with css too. Css tends to be faster than javascript fyiw

Comment: Yes, I basically wanted to create a replicate of it. I found out how they did it.They create separate `<span>` elements before and after the duplicated caret. They then used a `*.gif` containing the caret as a background-image of the 2. `<span>` element. When you type they dynamically change the content of the both `<span>` elements. This has the benefit that the text does not move with a moving caret as it is only in the background. Thanks for your help! Ahh and the blinking is done as you suggested via css.